# Am I sending a date object correctly to the request body? Python

Tags: python, post, request, urllib2, urllib

I am sending a POST request via python urllib and urllib2 libraries.
I am able to send the request, but it is ignoring the dates `(values)`.

In the documentation, it says I need to pass the date object on the request body. Bellow is the code I am using.

```
url = 'https://api.kenshoo.com/v2/reports/5233/runs/?ks=105'
values = {'dateRange': {'from':'2015-09-22', 'to':'2015-09-22'}}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)

req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
req.add_header('Content-Length', 0)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

From the API documentation, this is what I know about the date format.

> "The request body must contain a dates range in YYYY-MM-DD format, i.e.

```
 {"dateRange":{"from":"2014-10-20", "to":"2014-10-22"}}
```

The complete documentation for the request can be found here
http://docs.api.kenshoo.com/#!/Reports/runReport

Comment: you have to tell us how the document wants the dateRange to be formatted as.

Comment: Just updated my original post. If you're familiar with Chrome's Advanced Rest Client, I enter "{"dateRange":{"from":"2015-09-22", "to":"2015-09-22"}}" into the Payload section and it works. Not sure how to transfer that into my python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send JSON-formatted document, not urlencoded data:

```
url = 'https://api.kenshoo.com/v2/reports/5233/runs/?ks=105'
values = {'dateRange': {'from':'2015-09-22', 'to':'2015-09-22'}}
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(values))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also noticed that 'req.add_header('Content-Length', 0)'  was interfering with the passing of the date parameter..